# Google Drive API failing. Files:get response CORS error

Tags: javascript, api, cors, drive

I have a web application that relies on saving files to Google Drive and later retrieving them from the server. I am using the [Google API Javascript Client](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client) and using similar code to the Google Drive API example to retrieve the file. I use a request to the Google API get service to retrieve the file metadata and then I use that file's downloadUrl contained in the metadata to request that file through an XmlHttpRequest, retrieving the access token from the Google API.

```
getContents = function(fileId,callbackFunction) {
    var request = gapi.client.drive.files.get({ fileId : fileId});
    request.execute(function(metadata) {
        if(metadata.downloadUrl) {
            var connection = new haxe.Http(metadata.downloadUrl);
            var accessToken = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getAuthResponse(true).access_token;
            connection.setHeader("Authorization","Bearer " + accessToken);
            connection.async = true;
            connection.onData = function(data) {
                callbackFunction(metadata,haxe.io.Bytes.ofString(data));
            };
            connection.onError = function(error) {
                callbackFunction(metadata,null);
            };
            connection.request(false);
        }
    });
}
```

As recently as of yesterday, the Google API has stopped working when retrieving files. I can get the file metadata just fine, but when requesting the downloadUrl, it is blocked by the CORS policy because the Google API response does not contain the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header. I have made no changes to the relevant code for a long time, so I am at a loss as to why this suddenly stopped working. Does anyone have any insight as to the source of this problem?

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: same issue here, https://00e9e64bac41496ec3cc9a982a85466f82ad0f5e98ef18b221-apidata.googleusercontent.com/download/drive/v2/files/xxxx' (redirected from 'https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/xxxx') from origin 'https://example.com'  has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: The response has a 307 status code

Comment: @MarcAmorós solved the problem? same issue here, files.create ok, but files.update faces CORS error